How do i fit a object to special terrain
So I have been constructing a race track and found a location that I would like it to be at I made the terrain scale to that part of the world using BlenderGIS but I am having trouble fitting the track to the layout. I used a square and extended it to make the track. I would really appreciate the help from anyone and I will try any ideas and give feedback on how it works. Thanks. 

First thing that comes to mind is the Shrink Wrap modifier, the second is the Knife Project tool. Either way, you’ll have to extrude the track afterwards.

As @TheLabCat already mentioned, the shrink-wrap modifier should work well for your task. Make sure to give it a subdivision modifier (place it above the the shrink-wrap modifier!) if the Track does not have enough geometry to adjust itself well on the ground. To give it some depth you can either apply the modifiers and extrude the track or ad a solidify modifier after the shrink-wrap.
I personally would recommend to edit the landscape as no track would ever be in a 30 degree angle. they would excavate the ground where the track would be to make it flat before building it.

thanks it seemed to work and i just have to do a bit of remodeling to flatten it out overall it should work out well. Thanks!

i finished it and it looks great thanks for the feedback it really helped

Sounds great! Happy I could help. If the problem is resolved you can accept my Answer. This way the Question gets displayed as solved
